# JPA and native FK constraints

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am a pretty beginner of JPA. So I created my first project using a database first strategy, e.g. I define my Database Schema by hand and then use JPA to access it.

When it comes to relationships i use this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "action", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
```

So, JPA takes care of deletion (`CascadeType.ALL`, `orphanRemoval`)

Now I was thinking if it was a good idea to add `foreign key constraints` to the database schema as well? (Currently I don't have it):

`ALTER TABLE T_FOO ADD CONSTRAINT t_fk foreign key (BAR_ID) REFERENCES T_BAR(ID) on delete cascade`

What do you think will it be a good idea or will this yield to problems with JPA?

Comment: I'd guess that your JPA provider will get confused since you told it to cascade and the records disappear outside its context

Comment: If you want the database to handle cascading the deletes instead of the applications, you will need to let JPA provider know.  See http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_cascadeondelete.htm for how to do this in EclipseLink

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea. You should create database schema with primary, foreign keys and correct data types. Nothing more.